# How to sort an array A using an array S with the properties below

Tags: sorting

- A is an array of size n of different numbers (not necessarily integers). Indexes start from $1$ to $n$.
- S is an array with the property:
  $$S[i] = |\left\{A[j] \  : 1\le j<i \ \text{and} \ A[j] \le A[i]\right\}| $$
  For example, for  $A=[2,7, 4,5,15,9,12]$ , $S=[0,1,1,2,4,4,5]$.

---

I want to sort $A$ with time complexity  of $o(n \log n)$ using $S$.

I'm trying to sort $A$ with time complexity of $O(n)$.

I know that we can know where to put the last element (which is $12$ in our case). There are $S[7]=5$ elemets before $A[7]=12$ that are smaller than $12$. That means if $A'$ is sorted array of $A$, then $A'[6]=12$.

I need help with how to continue my idea or suggest another way to sort A.

Comment: If you place the numbers from last to first at their sorted position as you suggest then if we place $A[i]$ with $S[i] = k$, then $A[i]$ goes to the $k+1$-st unoccupied position in $A'$.

Comment: @HendrikJan I tried that but notice it doesn’t work for $A[5]=15$.

Comment: After placing A[7] and A[6] in the new (sorted) array, it looks thus: [-,-,-,-,9,12,-]. Then S[5] = 4, so A[5]=15 goes to 5th free position in that partial filled array. Which is the last position.

Comment: Note this only explains (I hope) how to continue using the array $S$. I have no clue actually how this speeds up the sorting. We have to record the free positions in some efficient way.

Comment: @HendrikJan Thanks. I thought about that I'm not convinced it's $O(n)$.

Comment: @HendrikJan How do you know where is the 5th free position with $O(1)$?

Comment: My remark only suggests how to use $S$. I do not know how to find the $k$th free position in constant time. (That is why I made a comment instead of an answer.)